# Barteksc Android PDFView library not handling incomplete or corrupted PDF files correctly

Tags: android, pdfview

I'm currently using the (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2) PDFView library in my Android application to display PDF files. The problem is that when the PDF file is incomplete or corrupted, the library still attempts to open it, resulting in a white view. No Exception is being thrown So I have no idea how to handle it.

```
void loadFile(){
        try {
            myPDFViewer.fromFile(pdfFileName)
                    .defaultPage(2)
                    .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
                    .load();
        } catch (Exception e){
            Intent start = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Downloader.class);
            start.putExtra("pdfFileName", pdfFileName);
            startActivity(start);
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Can someone guide me on how to handle incomplete or corrupted PDF files using the PDFView library So that it don't show blank page? How can I ensure that the file is a valid PDF before attempting to load it? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If your library isn't handling the input correctly, use a different library.

Comment: @KJ You're asking for internal implementation details of a PDF viewer that isn't one of the commonly used ones, and who's project hasn't seen a checkin for 5 years.  It could be anything, and since nobody is working on the project you're not going to have too much luck finding someone to fix the issue.  I really suggest moving to a library that's under active development.  There's dozens of pdf libraries out there.  For security updates alone using that library is a bad idea.

Comment: https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer/commits/master/ shows the last commit was in 2019.

Comment: And that viewer is just view code around another library that actually decodes the pdfs-  which hasn't seen an update in 6 years.  This is dead code all the way down.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Actually I knew I can move on to other library. But I am a learner so I Thought "am I doing something wrong? Is there any other method to do what I want?" That's why I asked this qusstion to learn something I don't know.

Comment: Actually, in my project if app do not find the required pdf the app, app downloads the pdf automatically. But the problem occurs when download got interrupted by user force closing the app. Then as the pdf file is exist the app avoid redownload it and try to open it. But after not getting a solution for that I just solve it by renaming it as a non-file type file when downloading. Then rename it back as .pdf when download complete. Then that app can't open a non-file type file so it redownload pdf even if previous download got interrupted. That's how I solve it. Thank you.